# Count number of points outside confidence interval (CI) in qqp (Quantile-Comparison Plot) plot

Tags: r, performance, plot, distribution, data-fitting

I've like to find any function for calculated number of points outside confidence interval (CI 95%) in qqp (Quantile-Comparison Plot) plot.

In my example:

Packages

```
require(MASS)
require(car)
```

Simulated 60 Poisson values

```
Resp<-rpois(60,1)
```

Fitting Binomial negative dstribution

```
nbinom <- fitdistr(Resp, "Negative Binomial")
```

Plot using qqp

```
qqp(Resp, "nbinom", size = nbinom$estimate[[1]], mu = nbinom$estimate[[2]])
```

[image: qqp plot]

Now I would like to use any function for create a vector with the numbers of points outside confidence interval (CI) in qqp (Quantile-Comparison Plot) plot. This is possible? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

qqp() doesn't count the number of points outside the confidence envelope but it computes the information that's needed to get this count. You can simply modify the code (`car:::qqPlot.default`) if you change:

```
outerpoints <- sum(ord.x > upper |  ord.x < lower)
print(outerpoints)
if (length(outerpoints) > -1) 
    outerpoints
else invisible(NULL)
```

the output show the number of points outside the confidence envelope.

Comment: You don't show how you've defined ord.x, upper, or lower. It's unclear how this follows from your question

Comment: ord.x, upper, or lower is present in original qqp() function.

Comment: Where? Running your code, none of those variables are either in my environment or attributes of any output of `qqp`. Your solution depends on 3 undefined variables, and therefore throws an error, which doesn't make it very useful for other SO users